# Do 2 objects creating serial queues with the same name share the same queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Not sure on the behavior, because I suspect I am getting a deadlock,

I have a class with multiple objects - each object creates a queue with the same name. I'm not sure if GCD is reusing the same queue between the objects or if they just share the same name.

For instance

```
@interface MyClass

-(void)doSomeWork
@property (nonatomic,strong) dispatch_queue_t myQueue;

@end

@implementation MyClass

-(id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  self.myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
  return self;
}

-(void)doSomeWork
{
  dispatch_async(self.myQueue,^{
    // some long running work
  });
}

@end


@interface SomeClassWhichCreatesALotOfObjects

@end


@implementation SomeClassWhichCreatesALotOfObjects

-(void)someMethod
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    MyClass *object = [MyClass new];
    [object doSomeWork]; // are these running in serial to each other or are each offset to the queue their object has created? Can't understand from the debugger
  }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As Apple's documentation states, the label is:

> A string label to attach to the queue to uniquely identify it in debugging tools such as Instruments...

It is used as a hint, nothing more.

**EDIT**

Here's the code you want for using a shared queue.

```
+ (dispatch_queue_t)sharedQueue
{
    static dispatch_queue_t sharedQueue;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
    });
    return sharedQueue;
}
```

Comment: so they are separate queues. Now how can i create one queue used amongst objects of the same class

Comment: Is it ok to pass the queue name string as a parameter to this function? @GuyKogus

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. `dispatch_once` is guaranteed to only call once for the entire lifetime of the program, so passing in the name as a parameter in my implementation would only work for the first call to the method.

Comment: If you want to have multiple shared queues, what you would need is a dictionary of queues mapping the names to the queues. Not sure how good of an idea this is, for multiple reasons. It would probably be better to store the queue in a place that makes sense for reuse by whoever needs it.

Comment: @AvnerBarr, you can use static keyword for it. After all static is same for all objects of same class.

Comment: @AvinashB you would still be creating different queues, even if the names are the same (using a static keyword or hardcoded string or anything else).

Comment: @AvnerBarr, what ever you said is right if you want to create it every time. Check if a reference exists and then create.

Answer (score 18):

`dispatch_queue_create` does exactly what the name suggests, it creates a dispatch queue. The label you give it is not required to be unique, it is just used for debugging purposes.