# Confusion regarding ->> dispatch_queue_create ...?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Currently in my code am using

`dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", nil) , { () -> Void in`

Now I have the necessity in my code to call this code **many times** ...

So my question is whenever each time I call the above mentioned statement I want to know whether am posting the task to the **same queue** or each time when I call am **creating a new queue** ??

Pls guide me if any one came across the same problem...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do 2 objects creating serial queues with the same name share the same queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421283/do-2-objects-creating-serial-queues-with-the-same-name-share-the-same-queue)

Comment: why does it matter actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the queue you are creating is local to the scope of method from where you are calling it, you can not get any detail of the queue after the method is executed.

What you can do is create this queue as a global variable out of all methods. Thus your queue will be created only one time

```
let myQueue : dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", nil)
.
.
.
.
// then you can use it in this way anytime you want:

dispatch_async(myQueue , { () -> Void in
```